# Git - work in new feature while some needed class are on pull request

Tags: git, version-control

I just finished a feature (`feature1`) and created a pull request for it to be merge to `master`. I want to start working on another feature (`feature2`) but some functionalities I need was just introduced on `feature1`. What is the best way to start working in a new feature while some needed functionalities are still on pull request? There are also other pull requests which might be merged before `feature1`

Should I create a `feature2` branch out of my local master and then merge the `feature1` locally:

```
    git checkout master
    git pull origin master
    git checkout -b feature2
    git merge origin/feature1
```

or should I create `feature2` from `feature1` branch then just merge changes in the master after sometime:

```
    git checkout feature1
    git checkout -b feature2
    ... commits
    git checkout master
    git pull origin/master
    git merge origin/master
```

Which is better? Do you have a more correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideologically you never work on an unreviewed branch! However if you know "feature1" is good and ait gonna be rejected then simply create a new branch over "feature1" and start working. After sometime you can "rebase" your feature2 over "master" and if "feature1" is promoted to master then the commits designated for "feature1" will nolonger be a part of your "feature2" branch!

Your answer your second approach is correct but rebasing is more cleaner!